# Writing a simple text file to Google Cloud Storage from PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, filesystems, fopen

When I try to use the sample code:

```
$fp = fopen("gs://my_bucket/some_file.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, "Hello");
fclose($fp);
```

I get this error:

> Warning: fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper "gs" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

**UPDATE**

Switching to running the app server from the command line made the original error go away but I now get this error:

'`google\appengine\runtime\RPCFailedError' with message 'Remote implementation for urlfetch.Fetch failed'`

Does anyone know how I can resolve it?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: Unless you install a special driver, PHP doesn't know how to interpret URLs beginning with `gs:`.

Comment: You need to do more than just these 3 lines of code (actually these three lines could be written as a single line, but that's not the point here), see [Google Cloud Storage PHP API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "file_put_contents" instead of "fopen" fixed the problem for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing this error? On the production server, testing locally using our SDK or are you not using the SDK?

We install this handler as part of our setup script, so you need to be running in the dev appserver if your testing locally.

Comment: I am running locally using the dev appserver, so I must be missing something obvious. Is there something I need to do besides these three lines of code as @hakre suggests?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dev_appserver.py (from GAE PHP SDK) to check your code locally. Do not run it through your local webserver, since it will not provide additional plugins (for example gs: stream support) and won't emulate "whole" GAE environment (Datastore, Memcache, Tasks etc.).

On Debian following should work:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
/path/to/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi .
```

assuming that:

1. you have downloaded and installed [GAE PHP SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installing)
2. you're in your GAE test application directory

You will have to enter localhost website on port 8080 to check if you have your app working. On localhost port 8000 you have admin server in which you can check data in your local Datastore.

After that you can place phpinfo() in your .php file to check if you have 'gs' supported in "Registered PHP Streams" row.

Comment: I am using GoogleAppEngineLauncher (OSX) which should be the same as running from the command line? The reason I am doing so is that when I try to run from the command line I get errors:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 182, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
NameError: global name 'execfile' is not defined

Comment: I do not see any errors when I use GoogleAppEngineLauncher and the app is served. I only run into problems when I try to use the 'gs:' stream wrapper.

Comment: The errors when running from the command line are most likely do to the fact that I have more then one python version installed, but when I run from GoogleAppEngineLauncher it locates the correct python version.

Comment: I changed my master python version to 2.7 and I can now run the app server from the command line, only now I am see a different error when I try to use the "gs:" stream wrapper:

!Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\runtime\RPCFailedError' with message 'Remote implementation for urlfetch.Fetch failed' google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RemoteApiProxy.php on line 105

Comment: Have you tried admin panel on port 8000? Can you view content of Datastore Viewer? Can you create new entity in there?

Comment: Good suggestion. I can create a new entity there, also I can see the entity created by my script, here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing: [http://i719.photobucket.com/albums/ww191/evan108108/dataviewer.png~original](Datastore Viewer Screenshot). It looks like the entity is getting created but I'm still getting the error...

Comment: "This indicates a bug in the remote implementation." so if it works for now I suppose they will fix it in the next SDK iteration. Also it looks like to upgrade python to 2.7 is the answer for your question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. While it's true that I switched default python to version 2.7 so that I could run the server from the command line and that did make a difference, it does not explain why the GoogleAppEngineLaucher which I pointed at python27 did not work...  

Is anyone else out there having this issue? Does anyone at Google know what might be going on? I would love to get this going on my local.  

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As the error suggests, the wrapper i.e. 'gs' is undefined.

Their are some build-in wrappers by php that can be used in fopen php function; for the custom wrappers i.e. 'gs' in your case, stream_wrapper_register php function can be used.

Reference links:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php